# Bourbon soaked oak cubes

Tags: secondary-fermentation

I have made a ten tidy clone using the 1st runnings method.  Which left me with 3 gallons after boil.  I transferred from the primary to secondary and I am currently ready to add the bourbon soaked oak cubes (american medium plus toast), which was a ratio of 12 oz bourbon to 2 oz of cubes.  My question is how long do you recommend soaking the bourbon oak cubes in the secondary before bottling?

Comment: Are you referring to the Ten FIDY?

Answer (score 3):

For the bourbon flavor, the effect is rapid. However, for the wood, you'll want to keep that in for a few weeks. However, bourbon will likely mask much of the oak that you will extract.

Comment: That would agree with my experience. I used a recipe kit with bourbon + oak in the secondary. Recipe said 6+ months for the secondary but a house move meant I only had 3 months. Too much bourbon flavour! although post bottling, the flavour is slowly balancing. Next time I'll use less whisky and age longer. Perhaps increasing the oak chips might help?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tasted a "ten tidy" yet, but based on my experience with wine and oak chips, I would say that one week is enough to get some wood taste.  After 2 weeks, I felt the oak taste was too strong for a wine.

So according to that experience, I would say that after a week take a small sample to taste.  Then decide if you'd like to leave it more time or not.  Take another sample every 2-3 days until you are satisfied with the amount of extraction.

Answer (score 1):

wild stab in the dark here but I think it makes sense. I have several jars of varying chars of oak in different whiskeys and wines. I plan on pulling them out, soaking them in another jar of like beer to be brewed, and then adding to full batch. My hope is this would simulate a second (brewers) use barrel and at the very least less aggressive and could work from there.